# Get top entry of each RDD while using distinct

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

I have some data which changes over time and I am keeping it in cassandra. UserId is the partition key and date of stamping is the clustering key ordered descending and the data. My expectation was that if I query this from Spark and run a .distinct on it I will get the top most entry for each UserId thereby giving me the latest data. But it looks like it is not doing that.

Is there any way to get the data corresponding to the latest date apart from reducing the data and passing a function which chooses the recent dated data for every comparison.

[EDIT]

```
Sample:  
Userid: 1  
    Date: 8/15/2015  
        Location: Building 1  
        ...   
    Date 8/1/2015  
        Location: Building 5  
        ...  
Userid: 2  
    Date: 7/30/2015  
        Location: Building 10  
        ...
    Date: 6/1/2015  
        Location: Building 3  
        ...
```

So as per my requirement, when for user 1, I want Building 1 as location and building 10 for user 2.

Spark version 1.2.2

Comment: Can you post a sample? If the data is ordered, then simply calling `first` should work...

Comment: @JustinPihony won't first give me just the 1st RDD?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
rdd.toDF.groupBy("Userid").max("Date")
```

Comment: your solution is correct but I forgot to mention that I am using spark 1.2.2, so not marking it as the answer, instead corrected the question

Answer (score -1):

You can do one thing first connect with cassandra using spark then make dataframe of spark then convert dataframe into temptable then you can perform your query .